# InnoDB Slave not updating

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb

I have a primary MySQL server and am trying set up a replication for InnoDB database.
I perform a Master and Slave configuration, create a dump of Master station DB, restore it on Slave station and run replication. Everything looks fine but no updates are reflected on Slave. The Slave is running, the Read_Master_Log_Pos on Master and Slave are identical. I even look up the mysql-relay-bin.00000X file and there are updates from the Master. But no changes when I run "SELECT * FROM db.table;".
If I change BD engine to MyISAM everything works fine.
I also tried to create an empty database (InnoDB engine), dump it and restore from it on the Slave, start replication and then create tables on Master and fill them. In this case replication is doing well. But I also need a way to replicate already created and filled database.
What should I do?

I have:
my.cnf on Master:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
port=3306
replicate-do-db=gcm_data
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
server-id=8217
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
```

my.cnf on Slave:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
port=3306
replicate-do-db=gcm_data
relay-log-index=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
relay-log=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
server-id=50890
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
```

SHOW MASTER STATUS\G

```
File: mysql-bin.000001
Position: 657
Binlog_Do_DB:
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
```

SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: 10.0.13.52
Master_User: slave1
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry: 60
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 657
Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000004
Relay_Log_Pos: 251
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Replicate_Do_DB: gcm_data
Replicate_Ignore_DB:
Replicate_Do_Table:
Replicate_Ignore_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
Last_Errno: 0
Last_Error:
Skip_Counter: 2
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 657
Relay_Log_Space: 551
Until_Condition: None
Until_Log_File:
Until_Log_Pos: 0
Master_SSL_Allowed: No
Master_SSL_CA_File:
Master_SSL_CA_Path:
Master_SSL_Cert:
Master_SSL_Cipher:
Master_SSL_Key:
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_IO_Error:
Last_SQL_Errno: 0
Last_SQL_Error:
```

SHOW PROCESSLIST on Master:

```
| Id | User   | Host              | db   | Command     | Time | State                                                          | Info             |
| 16 | slave1 | 10.0.13.140:54683 | NULL | Binlog Dump | 2062 | Has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL             |
```

SHOW PROCESSLIST on Slave:

```
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State                                                                 | Info             |
| 14 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 2203 | Waiting for master to send event                                      | NULL             |
| 15 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 2203 | Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it | NULL             |
```

If it is somehow important I'm running both Master and Slave station from virtual CentOS 6.0, MySQL 5.1.61.

## UPDATE

I implemented a little behavior test: I created am empty database on `Master`, run a replication script (everything went well - `Master` and `Slave` were running). Then I created an `InnoDB` table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT, data VARCHAR(10)) engine=InnoDB;
```

The table appeared on Slave. Then I filled table with data

```
INSERT tbl values (1, "1");
```

The data was updated on Slave.

Then I stopped Master (`service mysqld stop`) and Slave IO also stopped

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS - Slave_IO_Running: No, Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

Then I started MySQL on Master and Slave IO also started in some time. But since updates are not available on Slave, hence they are present in `mysql-relay-bin.00000X` on Slave.

Comment: Switching to myisam making it work makes it sound like you're not committing transactions before checking for changes on the slave.

Comment: I not actually using a transactions right now. I'm testing using "INSERT db.table (C1, C2) VALUES (V1, V2);" on Master and "SELECT * FROM db.table;" on both Master and Slave to track updates. On Master updates are available, on Slave - not. The funny thing is that right now MyISAM db also isn't updated on Slave.

Comment: Why is Skip_Counter set to 2?

Comment: I was just trying different replication configurations. Didn't solve the problem. It didn't work with With Skip_Counter = 0 ether.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I somehow solved the problem. It seems that the problem is exactly in running both Master and Slave from virtual machines. I run the same replication script on real machines and everything is working just fine.
So now the question is why isn't it working on VM properly.

**UPDATE**

Some time ago same problem raised on the real machines.
And eventually I found the source of this problem:
I was testing my replication using INSERT/SELECT commands like this:
INSERT db.table (ID, VALUE) values (ID, 2);
on Master and checking:
SELECT * FROM db.table;
on Slave. And id didn't show me the updates.
But then I tried:
USE db;
INSERT table (ID, VALUE) values (ID, 2);
And update was available on Slave station.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check status by command show slave status\G
2. stop slave;
3. reset slave all;
4. At Slave Server show slave status\G;
5. stop slave;
6. reset slave all;
7. drop database dbname; (make sure to delete slave db)
8. create database slavedb;
9. restore backup of master db to slave db
10. check head count by command "head -25" to get log position from your newly restored backup file.
11. add binary file name
    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'Master IP', MASTER_USER = 'user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password',  MASTER_LOG_FILE='**mysql-masterdb-bin.002428**', **MASTER_LOG_POS=57508035**;
12. start slave;